# Extract Email and Put it in Adjacent Row

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have dataset.

```
v1 <- c("I will try to fix you usman@usman.com", "I will try to fix you", "Zombies Zombies xyz@ymail.com")
v2 < c("ABC", "XYZ", "Oh Game")
dx <- data.frame(v1, v2)
```

I extract the emails from `v1` using

`regmatches(dx$v1, regexpr("[[:alnum:]]+\\@[[:alpha:]]+\\.com", dx$v1))`

This works.

I just want to put the email adjacent to the `v2` in `dx`

such that.

```
ABC       usman@usman.com
XYZ       NA
Oh Game   xyz@ymail.com
```

Seems pretty basic but I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be

```
dx$emails <- sapply(dx$v1, function(x) {
  email <- regmatches(x, regexpr("[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alpha:]]+\\.com", x))
  (result <- ifelse(identical(email, character(0)), NA, email))
})
```

This basically checks if at least one match was found.

---

If you don't mind installing a package, use `stringr` and put parentheses around your expression (the `@` does not need to be escaped):

```
library(stringr)
dx$emails <- str_extract(dx$v1, "([[:alnum:]]+@[[:alpha:]]+\\.com)")
```

---

Both will yield

```
                                     v1      v2          emails
1 I will try to fix you usman@usman.com     ABC usman@usman.com
2                 I will try to fix you     XYZ            <NA>
3         Zombies Zombies xyz@ymail.com Oh Game   xyz@ymail.com
```

Comment: Hey @Jan,

Thanks, this seems to be working well and thank you for giving `base` and `stringr` solution.